# Flutter Build failure, Not running on physical device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Anytime I want to build my app on a physical device it always brings this error.

```
flutter (16557): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1220)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
F/libc    (16557): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16557 (ple.ncbc_bogije)
```

---

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltebmc/heroltebmc:8.0.0/R16NW/G930W8VLS8CTI1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 16557, tid: 16557, name: ple.ncbc_bogije  >>> com.example.ncbc_bogije <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1220)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
'
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000040ad  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
    x4   0000000000000080  x5   0000000000000080  x6   0000000000000080  x7   8000000000000000
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   c2b83b5796c0f061  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
    x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  0000000000000000  x14  ffffffffffffffff  x15  00006f736674d102
    x16  00000072e48b12f8  x17  00000072e4852408  x18  0000000012e234d0  x19  00000000000040ad
    x20  00000000000040ad  x21  0000007fca7dce88  x22  00000072bb3766f0  x23  00000072bb3766d8
    x24  000000000000003e  x25  0000007fca7dd0f8  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000001
    x28  000000000000003e  x29  0000007fca7dce60  x30  00000072e4804bd4
    sp   0000007fca7dce20  pc   00000072e4852410  pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000006b410  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
    #01 pc 000000000001dbd0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
    #02 pc 000000000000255c  /data/app/com.example.ncbc_bogije-Z4NKpiCW6ZWk_raUGK4byQ==/base.apk (offset 0x377f000)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: try restarting your physical device

Comment: I've done that but still not working

Comment: what is output of `adb devices` command

Comment: it like the build process keeps timing out @HasilT

Comment: My Physical device is SAMSUNG S7, while my emulator is Pixel 4 API 28 @Kozubi

Comment: white screen and  app has stopped @Kozubi

Comment: ok, but is says offline or something? Can you paste output here?

Comment: So basically anytime i try to build the app after the build process is completed and running the installation process, it displays the regular splash screen and it stops building and displays this **App has stopped** on the physical device and displays that error on the console.

Comment: Can you post your app/build.gradle file ,   to be more specific buildTypes present in buil.gradle file

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}